# I aim to write a program that will count and store the position of the occurence of a string within a character array

Tags: c++, arrays

The program will count the position where a specific string occurs within a character array and store that position within an array. As an example the string 'has' would be at positions [0,13,25,33] when compared to the string 'hassan is a hassler who hassles hasslers'. Two main character arrays are being used; str[] and sub[]. str being the string from where the occurrence is counted from and sub the string compared. I have attached my idea of the code. Any help is appreciated and as I am still a student and not a pro, I would very much appreciate constructive help rather than comments on how my code and workflow is sloppy. I wish to display the array with all the positions and the program does not display anything other than the return value, which for some reasons is mostly very big numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void allPositionsofSub()
{
    int nstr;
    int nsub;
    char str[100];  //i initially wished to use the variable nstr but it wouldnt work with cin.get
    char sub[nsub];
    cout<<"Enter the string: ";
    cin.get(str, 100);
    cout<<"Enter the sub: ";
    cin>>sub;
    int num;
    int count;
    int count1=0;
    int outdisplay[count];

    for(int nstr1=0;nstr1<=99;nstr1++)
    {
        char n;
        n = sub[nstr1];
        while (nstr1<=nsub)
        {
            if (n==str[nstr1])
            {
                outdisplay[num]=nstr1;// this is where i think the problem perhaps lies.
                num++;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    while(count1<=count)
    {
        cout<<outdisplay[count1]<<", ";
        count1++;
    }
    cout<<"-1";

}

int main()
{
    allPositionsofSub();
}
```

updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void allPositionsofSub()
{
    int nstr;
    int nsub=20;
    char str[100];
    char sub[20];
    cout<<"Enter the string: ";
    cin.get(str, 100);
    cout<<"Enter the sub: ";
    cin>>sub;
    int num;
    int count;
    int count1=0;
    int outdisplay[count];

    for(int nstr1=0;nstr1<=99;nstr1++)
    {
        char n;
        n = sub[nstr1];
            if (n==str[nstr1])
            {
                outdisplay[num]=nstr1;
                num++;
                count++;
            }

    }
    while(count1<=count)
    {
        cout<<outdisplay[count1]<<", ";
        count1++;
    }
    cout<<"-1";

}

int main()
{
    allPositionsofSub();
}
```

Comment: Can we assume that you are not permitted to use `std::string` and the various tools in the <algorithm> library that make this easier?

Comment: Note `char sub[nsub];` makes use of a non standard extension. In fully standard compliant C++ the size of an array must be a compile time constant. `nsub` is not constant. Nor is it initialized at the time `sub` is allocated, leading to a wildly unstable program. The size of the array cannot be guaranteed and may well be useless or impossible.

Comment: If you are allowed to use the standard library, then [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm) might help you.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, I am only allowed to use character strings.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I havent yet had the chance to study automata so i would rather mess things up if i meddled with that.

Comment: @user4581301 so i should ascribe a safe length to sub[] to undo that? like sub[20] would cater to most words right?

Comment: You probably have a megabyte or more of Automatic storage available, so go nuts on how big you want it. `char sub[1024];` shouldn't give you any problems, though making it larger than `str`'s size is pointless. You can't find a 101 character word in a 100 character string. Remember to guard the size of what you read from the user when reading into `sub` just like you did when reading into `str`.

Comment: Just to note a few issues (not exhaustive) that might give you some hint: (1) `nsub` is not a const expression but used as an array extent (which is available in C, not standard c++; and it is recommended not to use it). Also `nsub` is uninitialized, which make things worse (it has undetermined value when used). (2) In your while loop `while (nstr1<=nsub)`, neither `nstr1` nor `nsub` is changed. Either the program will not enter the loop or it will stuck in there forever.

Comment: I recommend investing some time in familiarizing yourself with the use of the debugger that came with your development environment. A debugger will allow you to execute the program at your speed, allowing you to closely inspect what the program does as it does it. It's a very useful tool that makes finding many bugs, like infinite loops, easy and most bugs much less difficult.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I will try that

Comment: @user4581301 I see, thanks.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I acted on that and replaced nsub with an int value. Same result, also got rid of the while loop.

Comment: @HassanIftikhar Update your code in the question as you fix bugs, so people can see your progress.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Done so

Comment: Addendum to @KaenbyouRin 's comment: Once people start providing actual answers rather than comments be careful in any edits you make to not invalidate the answers.

Comment: @user4581301 Will cater to that.

Answer (score 1):

So the basic idea is to enumerate over every position in the source string and check whether it is the start of your substring.

It is better for you to try implementing the following pseudo-code, and come back if you have any more questions.

```py
# substr_len: The length of the substring you are looking for.
# str_len: The length of the source string.
# result: An array of int with sufficient length.

let match_count = 0
for (i in range 0..str_len-substr_len)
    let match = true
    for (j in range 0..substr_len-1)
        if (substr[j] != str[i + j])
            match = false
            break
    if (match)
        result[match_count] = i
        match_count = match_count + 1
```